# Check if date ranges are sequential or contain gaps per category

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, gaps-and-islands

I have workers and months in which they worked. I want to find out which of the workers had an off time. Consider simple example:

[image]

On a graph it looks like this:
[image]

Desired result is:

```
+-----------+-----+
| worker    | gap |
+-----------+-----+
| worker001 | 1   |
+-----------+-----+
| worker002 | 1   |
+-----------+-----+
| worker003 | 0   |
+-----------+-----+
```

**Assumptions:**

- Each worker may have different starting date and different ending
  date.
- Table contains only the dates (months) when worker was at
  work.

I would welcome query but I would be grateful for just idea how to do it. My idea is as follows.

Check min and max dates for each worker. Generate sequences of months between those two days for each worker (don't know how). Join it to original table and check if there are nulls. If so, we have gaps.

Comment: How do you get a value of "1" for 'worker001'?  Also, tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: does the algorithm have to work when the year change ?

Comment: @Nemeros yes, through many years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pretty simple way to count the gaps is to count the number of months and look at the difference between the maximum and minimum:

```
select worker,
       (datediff(month, min(month), max(month)) + 1) - count(*) as nummissing
from t
group by worker;
```

Note:  This uses SQL Server syntax for the difference in months; that is just a convenience, most other databases have similar functionality.

Comment: Amazingly simple:-)

Comment: Then you need to count the number of missing working months and not the number of gaps ?

Comment: @Nemeros In the question I asked for list of workers with gaps. Each worker is gappy or not. But yes you are right! this answer counts missing months, not number of gaps. Number of gaps would be great, though I have not asked for it.

Comment: Just reverse. This worked for me: `(DATEDIFF(month,min([Mymonth]),max([Mymonth])) +1) -count(*)`

Answer (score 1):

I would go with some window function algorithm.

input test data :

```
create table tt (key varchar(10), dte date);

insert into tt values ('w1', '2017-12-01');
insert into tt values ('w1', '2017-11-01');
insert into tt values ('w1', '2015-12-01');
insert into tt values ('w1', '2015-11-01');
insert into tt values ('w1', '2016-01-01');
insert into tt values ('w1', '2016-02-01');
insert into tt values ('w1', '2016-05-01');
insert into tt values ('w1', '2016-06-01');
insert into tt values ('w2', '2016-02-01');
insert into tt values ('w2', '2016-03-01');
insert into tt values ('w2', '2016-05-01');
insert into tt values ('w3', '2016-01-01');
insert into tt values ('w3', '2016-02-01');
```

Then we use a window function to create group between date to retreive continuous working time.

From here we just need to do a count - 1, with an other group by expression, to have the numbers of gaps.

```
with tmp as (
 select key, 
 dte,
 dte - (row_number() over(partition by key order by dte) MONTHS) as rnk_month, 
 row_number() over(partition by key order by dte) as rnk_tot
 from tt)
select key, min(dte), max(dte), rnk_month 
from tmp
group by key, rnk_month
order by key, rnk_month
```

Trying the query with sqlServer Syntax ... (not sure it will work till i do not have sqls)

```
with tmp as (
 select key, 
 dte,
 dateadd(month, - row_number() over(partition by key order by dte), dte)  as rnk_month, 
 row_number() over(partition by key order by dte) as rnk_tot
 from tt)
select key, min(dte), max(dte), rnk_month 
from tmp
group by key, rnk_month
order by key, rnk_month
```

To explain a little more :

The function : **row_number() over(partition by key order by dte)** will outpout this for the worker 1 :

```
-----------------------------
Worker | Month     | rnk_tot
-----------------------------
w1     |2015-11-01 | 1
w1     |2015-12-01 | 2
w1     |2016-01-01 | 3
w1     |2016-02-01 | 4
w1     |2016-05-01 | 5
w1     |2016-06-01 | 6
w1     |2017-11-01 | 7
w1     |2017-12-01 | 8
```

Now if we substract the date with the rnk_tot considering rnk_tot as a month, we will have some new dates that will form some continuous group :

```
----------------------------------------
Worker | Month     | rnk_tot | rnk_month
----------------------------------------
w1     |2015-11-01 | 1       |2015-10-01
w1     |2015-12-01 | 2       |2015-10-01
w1     |2016-01-01 | 3       |2015-10-01
w1     |2016-02-01 | 4       |2015-10-01
w1     |2016-05-01 | 5       |2015-12-01
w1     |2016-06-01 | 6       |2015-12-01
w1     |2017-11-01 | 7       |2017-04-01
w1     |2017-12-01 | 8       |2017-04-01
```

From here you can do a group by on the worker and the rnk_month column to gatter continuous working time (that's what the query i posted do) :

```
----------------------------------------
Worker | Mth Min   | Mth Max  | rnk_month
----------------------------------------
w1     |2015-11-01 |2016-02-01|2015-10-01
w1     |2016-05-01 |2016-06-01|2015-12-01
w1     |2017-11-01 |2017-12-01|2017-04-01
```

And from here you can have the number of gaps.
So the final query could be :

```
with tmp as (
 select key, 
 dateadd(month, - row_number() over(partition by key order by dte), dte) as rnk_month
 from tt)
select key, count(distinct rnk_month) - 1 as gaps
from tmp
group by key
```

That will give this output for the test case i used :

```
-----------------
Worker | Gaps
-----------------
w1     | 2
w2     | 1
w3     | 0
```

Comment: There is some error in that code. Near the word MONTHS. At least SQL Server. What is that word meant to do? What is rnk_month?

Comment: Yeah, i used db2 before you specified it were for SqlS. Basicly rnk_month will be a Date. more in the answer to a cleaner explanation (i gonna edit it in few)

Comment: check the second query that should work with sqls, i explainend the main mechanism of the query